# Output sentences using keywords in java

Tags: java, eclipse, file, keyword

I am trying to write a program in Java that tags sentences from a text file. Each tag has an associated array of keywords. A tag is applied to a sentence if and only if the sentence contains one or more keywords belonging to the tag's array.

For e.g. I have two tags: faults, and adaption. In those tags' arrays, I have words such as Bugs, Fail etc, for faults, and  Polish, Clean up for adaption. One of the sentence will be 'BUG found and fixed', which would go into the faults category, hence it will input the sentence after the heading fault as it contains the word 'bug'. I searched online on how do it but can't seem to find anything.

This is the array list that I have made:

```
String[] faults = {
            "Misspelled",
            "Error",
            "Fixed",
            "Change",};
```

And

```
String[] adaption = {"Fixed comments",
        "Filters", "Polish","Adjust"};
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank you. :)

Comment: the String class has an 'indexOf()' function that returns -1 if not found or 0-n if found. To look in a line for a fault use code like `if (line.indexOf(fault[i]) >= 0)`. This does not use word boundaries so `line.indexOf('change')` would find 'change', 'changes' and 'unchanged'.

Comment: Would this work from words from the text file?

Comment: You must read one line from the text file (or one comment/message) into a string and then test it against all the keywords, one my one using `indexOf`. I called that string 'line' above.

Comment: I think it'll be a good choice to try different methods. So I'll try and see which one works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not realy easy to get what you want:) But i think i get it...

You have two arraylist due to your two group. `adaption` and `fault` would be the two group...

1. First you should read the entire text from your input to a String.
2. Second you should find with `String[] sentences = split()` the sentences, you should split in '.', ',', '!' and all sentence closing marks. You should use a regexp for this `split(.|?|!|)` can do it for the prototype.
3. Then you should split these sentences to words, you should split now --) `String[] words=split(\\s+)` so finding for whitespaces `\\s+` represent you all the whitespaces (`\t \r \n` and so on)
4. And finally you should iterate through your words array  with a for loop, and find matching with your members in your two or more group (adaption, fault) (with indexOf() or equals() string methods)... Obviously if you have exact matches in the words, you can use HashMap and like this `Group1.get("the word you present itareted")`, this can fast your app so much;)

I can write the source also for you, but i think better just to give you some hint, how to do it. If any help need, write
GL!

Comment: It's kind of hard to explain it, sorry. Thank you for the hints :). I'll try and do what you said, and see if the works.

Comment: Yeah, i know:) You are welcome. I updated my hints, so it is more clear i think.

And one final hint if you take from me;) I think if you have a more complex problem, please try to decomposite it to smaller ones, and steps... And then try to find a solution for this smaller problems/issues.

Comment: It clear now, as now I know what to look for when doing this :)

Comment: Hey, I'm confused on step four. I just wanted to know if I can use HashMap with the array that I made? Because the tutorials that I looked at does it one by one. Thank you. :)

Comment: yes you can use hashMap, especielly hashmap.get(Object key), and this will fasten your application. But without a code it is hart to tell you exactly how and where you should use.

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure if i understood your question correctly, but if so you might want to try Hashmap's instead. You will have a  pair, and using the .get() method on a specific you can retrieve its value.

Comment: I edited it, it was bit vague I guess. I'll try and look at Hashmap.

Comment: Yeah, I'll need to read up on it, and use it. Thank you for answering :)

Comment: ok if it works don't forget to mark the answer you like the most, cheers

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consult the documentation on [java.lang.String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to learn how to see if a string contains a certain substring (or how to split it up in words)... and look at [java.lang.HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), also.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do better by using regular expressions. For each category, define a regular expression pattern, and then try to match the pattern against each line of the file (I assume your phrases come line by line):

```
import java.util.regex.*;
// ...    

Pattern faults = Pattern.compile("Misspelled|Error|Fixed|Change");
Pattern adaption = Pattern.compile("Fixed Comments|Filters|Polish|Adjust");

// I assume I can read from BufferedReader 'in'.

for ( String line = in.readLine() ; line != null ; line = in.readLine() ) {
    if ( faults.matcher(line).find() ) {
        // Classify as fault
    }
    if ( adaption.matcher(line).find() ) {
         // Classify as adaption
    }
}
```

Note that the `find()` method returns `true` or `false` depending on whether a match was found or not.
I recommend you to take a look at the [Java documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) for the `java.util.regex` package, and/or, Jeffrey Friedl's book ["Mastering Regular Expressions"](http://regex.info/). Maybe the [Java Tutorial Regular Expressions Trail](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) can be helpful too.